# what is the USSD to get mobile number

Tags: android

i have an android application which requires to get the mobile number. i tried this

```
TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        String number = tm.getLine1Number();
```

but it returns null, after I read the documentation of the `TelephoneManager` I understood that some phones don't have the mobile number they are working on.

the solution was to send an USSD code to get it.

I couldn't find that, any help please?

Comment: At best, that would vary by device.

Comment: @CommonsWare by device or by network ?

Comment: You mean by carrier don't you?  USSD is implemented by the carrier-  it actually makes a "call" to a remote server to respond.  You can write simple client server apps in USSD, and did in the bad old days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

USSD isn't really supported in Android.  But even if you can get it to work, USSD codes vary by carrier

Comment: so lets forget about android, I just wants to know the USSD, you said it is vary by networks, right? so i have to ask the network provider to tell me right? is this against privacy please?